# Does the best approximation exists in a complete subspace of a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis

There are many condition to make the best approximation exist.

For example,

> If a subspace $A$ of a Hilbert space $H$ is **complete and convex**, then for any fixed point $x_0 \in H$, there exists an unique best approximation $y_0 \in H$, such that $$d(x_0,y_0)=\inf_{y\in A}d(x_0,y)$$

Now I'm wondering the following extension,

> If $A$ is only **complete**, does the best approximation of $A$ exists (not necessarily unique)?

For a special case, say,

> If $A$ is **complete and finitely dimensioned**, then the best approximation exists.

this is trivial by the fact that $f(y)=d(x_0,y)$ is continuous, that $A$ is closed and that compactness is equivalent to bounded closed in a finitely dimensioned normed space.

Now, how about $A$ is **complete and infinitely dimensioned**? Maybe some of you can help me.

Comment: A complete Hilbert space?

Comment: sorry, I've corrected that.

Answer (score 2):

If $e_n$ are an orthonormal basis of $H$, consider the sequence $a_n = (1+1/n) e_n$.  The set $A = \{a_n : \; n = 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is a closed (and thus complete) set, because the distance between any two members of $A$ is greater than $1$.  There is no best approximation of $0$: $\|a_n - 0\| = 1 + 1/n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, but the infimum is not attained.

Answer (score 0):

The weakest conditions I know to have existence and unicity are $H$ is an inner product space (not necesserly complete) and $A$ is convex and complete.